# Free Network Monitor

Tags: windows, sockets, network-monitoring

I am having trouble integrating two products, one of which is mine and they appear not to be talking. So I want to make sure they are communicating correctly. I had a look around for network monitor and found TCP Spy. This works but only shows 1 side of the conversation at a time (it has to run locally) I would ideally like to see both sides at the same time - but you can't run two copies of TCP Spy.

I've hit Sourceforge, but nothing seems to jump out - I'm a Windows developer, I don't have perl installed.

I've found a couple of others which are cripple-ware and totally useless, so I was wondering what do the SO guys use for watching the TCP conversation?

BTW - the 'not-written-here' product is not a browser.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tried Wireshark and Microsoft Network Monitor, but neither detected my (and the program I am trying to communicate with) transfer. If I had a day to sit and configure it I probably could get it working but I just wanted the bytes sent and, more specifically, bytes received.

In the end I found [HHD Software's Accurate Network Monitor](http://www.hhdsoftware.com/Products/home/accurate-network-monitor.html) software which did what I wanted it to, even if it was slight clunky.

Comment: When you say it didn't detect it do you really mean you were collecting everything and the packet you wanted wasn't there? I find that hard to believe. It doesn't need any configuration, it just works. Getting a sensible filter so it gets what you want and not loads of other crap is harder!

Answer (score 20):

[Wireshark](http://www.wireshark.org/) is a really good and mature network sniffer. It's been around for years.

- Deep inspection of hundreds of protocols, with more being added all the time
- Live capture and offline analysis
- Decryption support for many protocols, including IPsec, ISAKMP, Kerberos, SNMPv3, SSL/TLS, WEP, and WPA/WPA2
- Coloring rules can be applied to the packet list for quick, intuitive analysis
- Output can be exported to XML, PostScript®, CSV, or plain text

Answer (score 4):

I'm not sure if it does everything you want, but have you seen [WireShark](http://www.wireshark.org/) and the [Microsoft Network Monitor](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?familyid=18b1d59d-f4d8-4213-8d17-2f6dde7d7aac&displaylang=en)?

Answer (score 4):

[Wireshark](http://www.wireshark.org/) (previously Ethereal)

> Wireshark is an award-winning network protocol analyzer developed by an international team of networking experts.

Answer (score 4):

I use [wireshark](http://www.wireshark.org/). Very good and free.

Answer (score 3):

Wireshark, aka Ethereal comes with a fair amount of TCP sniffing functionality.

http://www.wireshark.org/

Answer (score 1):

With respect to using Windows and lacking Perl: Why not try [Strawberry Perl](http://strawberryperl.com)? It's a free Perl distribution that's run by the Perl community (specifically Adam Kennedy at the core), is easy to install, and wields the full power of [CPAN](http://search.cpan.org) out of the box.

Answer (score 0):

Strange that I did not see WireShark when I visited SourceForge. The top result of the 60 returned was a bizarre german thing.

Answer (score 0):

Wireshark is great.. but another option would be via PowerShell.  I've used the [Get-Packet](http://blog.sapien.com/index.php/2008/08/14/analyze-packet-reloaded/) script from Jeff Hicks at Sapien Technologies as a really lightweight packet sniffer.  You get custom objects representing your packets and can do whatever filtering you need to via PowerShell.  The other script in the pair is Analyze-Packet, which can summarize the results of a packet capture.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at [Tcpdump](http://www.tcpdump.org) It is not a full fledged GUI network analyzer (not at all) but it is usable in scripts. Since I am more a Linux person, I use it with Bash and Python, but you should be able to call it from powershell.

Comment: We use "tcpdump -s 0 -w tracefile" all the time on customer systems to get traces we can then take home and analyse with Wireshark

Comment: (actually we also need a "-i bond0" option on it or it defaults to eth0 and only gets some of the traffic)