# Using Java bufferedreader to get html from URL

Tags: java, html, url, character-encoding, bufferedreader

I'm trying to read all the html from a page using a buffered reader like follows

```
 String charset = "UTF-8";
 URLConnection connection = new URL(url).openConnection();
    connection.addRequestProperty("User-Agent", 
                    "Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 6.0; Windows NT 5.0)");
    connection.setRequestProperty("Accept-Charset", charset);
    InputStream response = connection.getInputStream();
    BufferedReader br = new  BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(response,charset));
```

then I'm reading it line by line like this:

```
String data = br.readLine();
while(data != null){
data = br.readLine();
}
```

the problem is I'm getting something like:

```
}$B!)(BL$B!)(Bu"~$B!)$(D"C(B|X$B!x!)!x(B}
```

I've tried this:

```
do {
        data = br.readLine();
        SortedMap<String, Charset> map = Charset.availableCharsets();
        for(Map.Entry<String, Charset> entry : map.entrySet()){
            System.out.println(entry.getKey());

            try {
                System.out.println(new String(data.getBytes(entry.getValue())));
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

        }
}while(data!=null)
```

and I'm not getting any readable html in any of them. This really weird since it was working fine until this morning and I didn't change anything..
What am I doing wrong here? is it possible that something changed in the website I'm trying to read? please help.

Comment: Looks like you're accessing a data-stream or a encrypted site... But impossible to say without knowing the URL...

Comment: well.. how can I know this site is encrypted? thanks for the reply

Comment: Look at the protocol, is it https? Do you access a domain or a url with deeper paths? Then perhaps that is simply a stream... But as I said there's nothing sure without the url... If you want to keep it secret, don't ask for help, and inform yourself about network protocols....

Comment: Verify the url in debugger and open it with your browser,what do you see? Normal page, error, or does something start downloading?

Comment: Thanks Marvin but I don't think this is the issue, it is over http, I verified the url in the debugger, it is a normal page: [link](http://www.solarmovie.is/)
like I said it was working just fine yesterday.
I was going through the files that were created, some of them are not properly formed (generated files have forbidden characters in their names). Could it be that this is what caused it? it practically stopped in the the middle: some files were generated properly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Server has changed his transfer mode to compressed data, what you can see in response header from server:

```
Connection:keep-alive
Content-Encoding:gzip
Content-Type:text/html; charset=utf-8
Date:Mon, 09 Mar 2015 09:34:41 GMT
Server:nginx
Transfer-Encoding:chunked
Vary:Accept-Encoding
X-Powered-By:PHP/5.5.16-pl0-gentoo
```

As you can see the content encoding is set to gzip `Content-Encoding:gzip`.
So you have to decode the zipped content first:

```
GZIPInputStream gzis = new GZIPInputStream(connection.getInputStream());
BufferedReader br = new  BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(gzis,charset));
```

---

To view the headers of requests and responses you could use a network monitor (see [Free Network Monitor](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28302/free-network-monitor)).

Simpler is it to use the developer plugins integrated in most common browsers. Here is the documentation of Chrome DevTools, how to use the network tab: https://developer.chrome.com/devtools/docs/network

Comment: Thanks  Marvin, I apreciate it. Can you tell me where did you find this information the content type and encoding??

Comment: If you appreciate it vote the answer up, too :) I've edited the answer so have a look at it ;)