# Is there a way to get all the network requests a windows app using?

Tags: windows, desktop-application

I have a Windows Application (EXE) GETH CLIENT, which runs on my machine and I would like to get a log of all the network requests it is making (http, https, rpc etc.)

How to get such an insight?

Like "Developer Tools" for browser, is there any way to find such info for a running Windows Application?

Comment: Typical job for a firewall or a network monitor. See e.g https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28302/free-network-monitor